# Diagnosing battery issues on laptop

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, battery

[image]

My Thinkpad T540 laptop (8 yrs old) developed battery issues. It wouldn't run for more than 1/2 hour without being plugged in. I took it into a computer shop who ran some tests, determined that the battery was indeed bad, ordered a new one, which I took home yesterday.

Not satisfactory - and, in one way, worse. When plugged in the laptop says "not charging" even though the indicator says 24%. Even more telling, with the old battery, one could unplug the charger and still have the laptop run. Now it immediately turns off on unplugging. However, it will start when unplugged. Another test I tried was removing the battery and just leaving the charger plugged in. It will start that way as well.

Having read all the stuff available from googling this problem, I find nothing that describes this situation.  It's mostly on the level of "make sure the cords are tightly plugged in". I'm looking for a technical explanation.

I am looking for a way to test this situation.  The computer is a dual boot with options for Ubuntu 22.04 or Windows 10. I can install any test suite one might recommend. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this? I am afraid something is screwed up on the motherboard, and I would hate to have to part with this computer.

Comment: There are two possibilities.  You have a non-authenticate battery Chinese clone and it's horrible quality or the battery while being perfectly acceptable isn't an exact replacement for the original part so it doesn't fully support your device (in other words the battery doesn't 100% fit your device).  It's unlikely to be your motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, it looks the same as the old battery.  (See added picture). I saw them put it in yesterday.  Doesn't mean it isn't bad. I do see Chinese typography, but then aren't Lenovo's made in China? However thanks for telling me that it's unlikely to be the motherboard. Can you offer more information on why that is? I'm about to take it back to the shop.

Comment: Do take the battery back.  Also for Lenovo and within that time frame, you should be able to manage the battery with Battery Threshold Management.  I did that with my nine year old X230 and the second Lenovo battery is holding up well.

Comment: @John what’s battery threshold management? Thanks.

Comment: The commonly accept "always plugged in" is to charge to 80% and not beyond. My Laptops (all Lenovo) are always on (still somewhat locked down) and set to 80%. Works fine.